# Как сравнить 2 HashSet C#?

Tags: c#, hashset

Есть 2 HashSet объекта:

```
HashSet<string> one = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> two = new HashSet<string>();

// добавим для примера значения
one.Add("Hello");
two.Add("World");

// дальше я хочу проверить одинаковы ли значения в этой коллекции (значений в реальной коллекции больше 1000)
```

В общем говоря, алгоритм должен делать следующее: в коллекцию ```one``` записываем строки из dataGridView1, затем в коллекцию ```two``` записываем строки из другой таблицы dataGridView2, после эти коллекции сравниваю между собой и вывожу значение из коллекции ```One``` при условии ```One != Two```.

Comment: `one.equals(two)` ?

Comment: Да. Забыл уточнить, нужно получить значение ```one``` (строку), в случае, если ```one != two```

Comment: @tym32167 а так, этот метод работает

Comment: @tym32167 может через листы делать?

Comment: вот это `нужно получить значение one (строку), в случае, если one != two` смысла не имеет. One - это хешсет, а не строка. Добавьте пояснения с прмерами в свой воппрос.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: [SetEquals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=net-5.0)

Comment: `var result = one.Where(o=>two.Contains(o) == false).ToList();`

Comment: @tym32167 можно объяснить этот код? Дабы понимать как это работает, буду благодарен (уже).

Comment: этот код означает `взять все элементы из one которых нет в two и поместить в список, записать список в переменную result`

Comment: @tym32167 вместо ```o``` надо подставить свои значения?

Comment: нет, надо только вместо one и two подставить свои хешсеты.

Comment: @tym32167 ок, благодарю. Попробовал, теперь через ```foreach``` не показывает элементы списка

Comment: это плохо или хорошо? Что у вас в хешсетах при этом?  я не экстрасенс, если вы не показываете код, я не могу по нему что либо сказать :) \

Comment: @tym32167 разобрался только что)) просто сделал вместо ```var result``` => ```List<string> result = excelTable.Where(o => mysqlTable.Contains(o) == false).ToList();```, спасибо тебе еще раз, не раз уже выручал)

Comment: На здоровье! Хорошо, что всё получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить все элементы из первого хешсета, которые отсутствуют во втором, можно использовать это

```
var result = one.Where(o=>two.Contains(o) == false).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Если вам нужна именно разность `HashSet`-ов, в качестве альтернативного решения можно воспользоваться либо встроенной функцией `ExceptWith`:

```
one.ExceptWith(two);
```

(она не возвращает в ответ новое множество, а убирает из `one` те элементы, которые есть в `two`, но вам, кажется, такое и надо)

либо LINQ-функцией `Except`:

```
var diff = one.Except(two).ToList();
```

Если же вам нужно действительно лишь проверить множества на равенство между собой, достаточно использовать функцию `SetEquals`:

```
bool isEqual = one.SetEquals(two);
```